# How do i make next page button in android (click to go next fragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm newbie in Android coding. I try to make next button on MainActivity and I want to click and go to next fragment(I have 3 fragments). Please guide me. My code as below.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private ViewPager mFmPager;
private TextView mTvSkip;
private Button mBtnNext;

private String TAG =  "Main" ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTvSkip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSkip);
    mBtnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFooter);
    mFmPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.fmPager);

    mBtnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Click");

            //TODO make next page(fragment) button

        }

    });
    final MyPageAdapter adapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    Log.i(TAG,"onCreate");
    final RadioGroup mRdGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdGroup);

    mFmPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    mRdGroup.check(R.id.rdBtn1);
                    mTvSkip.setText("SKIP");
                    mBtnNext.setText("NEXT");
                    Log.i(TAG,"Case 0");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mRdGroup.check(R.id.rdBtn2);
                    mTvSkip.setText("SKIP");
                    mBtnNext.setText("NEXT");
                    Log.i(TAG,"Case 1");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mRdGroup.check(R.id.rdBtn3);
                    mTvSkip.setText(null);
                    mBtnNext.setText("LET'S SIGN UP");
                    Log.i(TAG,"Case 2");

                    // mBtnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    //   @Override
                    // public void onClick(View view) {
                    //   Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DummyPage.class);
                    // startActivity(i);
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "go to dummy sign up page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //}
                    //});
                    break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });


    mTvSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DummyPage.class);
            startActivity(i);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "go to dummy sign up page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    mFmPager.setAdapter(adapter);

  }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
}

public int getCount(){
    return 3;
}

public Fragment getItem(int position){
    if (position == 0)
        return new OneFragment();
    else if (position == 1)
        return new TwoFragment();
    else if (position == 2)
        return new ThreeFragment();
     return null;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Checkout 'fragment transactions'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy to do it with your `ViewPager`:

```
mFmPager.setCurrentItem(mFmPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true);
```

Comment: Where should I put it? Can you tell me exactly? Thank you.

Comment: Inside your `onClick` implementation for `mBtnNext` of course

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change your Fragments, you need to use `FragmentManager` and its methods.

Comment: Detailed instructions - https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this put this in your Activity.

```
 public static void setFragmentPage(int i) {
            pager.setScrollDurationFactor(1);
            pager.setCurrentItem(i, true);        
        }
```

Call this in your Fragment Button

```
activity.setFragmentPage(0);
```